# VOICE_DOWNLINK doesn't work?

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an application that records a phone call. I did use Android's `AudioSource.MIC`, `AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION`, `AudioSource.VOICE_CALL` and `AudioSource.VOICE_DOWNLINK` but all I hear is from the outgoing side.
And When i use `AudioSource.Voice_DOWNLINK`, like below occurs error.

```
02-26 16:23:44.292: E/MediaRecorder(9483): start failed: -2147483648
02-26 16:23:44.293: W/System.err(9483): java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
02-26 16:23:44.293: W/System.err(9483):     at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
02-26 16:23:44.293: W/System.err(9483):     at com.mypackage.startRec(Recorder.java:29)
02-26 16:23:44.293: W/System.err(9483):     at com.mypackage.onStartCommand(RunService.java:336)
02-26 16:23:44.293: W/System.err(9483):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3010)
02-26 16:23:44.293: W/System.err(9483):     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(ActivityThread.java)
02-26 16:23:44.294: W/System.err(9483):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1442)
02-26 16:23:44.294: W/System.err(9483):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-26 16:23:44.294: W/System.err(9483):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
02-26 16:23:44.294: W/System.err(9483):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
02-26 16:23:44.294: W/System.err(9483):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-26 16:23:44.294: W/System.err(9483):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
02-26 16:23:44.294: W/System.err(9483):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

And below is MediaRecorder source.

```
public static void record(String path){
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_DOWNLINK);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
        mRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(Path);
        try {
            mRecorder.prepare();
            mRecorder.start();
            mIsStart = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            stopRec();
            File file = new File(Path);
            file.delete();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        mRecorder.stop();
        mRecorder.reset();
        mRecorder.release();
        mRecorder = null;
        mIsStart = false;
    }
}
```

My test phone is Nexus5 and Android 6.0.1.

Thank you for reviewing it.
Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: You cant record call on Android anymore

Comment: Oh..Could you give me the information if you don't mind?

Comment: I was working on Call recording for few years. You can install any app in the market, they will record the only one side and other side voice will be low. As per my knowledge, only one guy became successful recording both ways using some NDK code and he started licensing code for money. `Automatic Call Recorder
`

Comment: I see. Thank you for the information. Let's find out one more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many countries recording calls is not legal and devices does not support `AudioSourcec.VOICE_DOWNLINK`, `AudioSourcec.VOICE_UPLINK` and `AudioSourcec.VOICE_CALL`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16273755/3969880)

Comment: According to your link, some devices are supported, but most are not. right?

Comment: Yes, I have encountered this kind of problem before. To check my device supports these or not I installed 3 call recorder app from google play, in select audio source settings of all apps VOICE_DOWNLINK, VOICE_UPLINK and VOICE_CALL was disabled.

Comment: Okay, Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at documentation of [`AudioSourec.VOICE_DOWNLINK`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html#VOICE_DOWNLINK), it is clearly stated that:

> Capturing from VOICE_DOWNLINK source requires the [**CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT) permission. This permission is reserved for use by system components and is not available to third-party applications.

So, you can't use `AudioSource.VOICE_DOWNLINK` as `audioSource` for recording calls.

Comment: That added in my AndroidManifest.xml. Sorry I don't attach AndroidManifest.xml source.