# AudioPlaybackCapture API for call recording

Tags: android, audio-recording

Is it possible to use [AudioPlaybackCapture](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/playback-capture) API for call recording?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but call recording can be done via another API. The app must specify `VOICE_CALL` media source for `MediaRecorder.AudioSource` and have `CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT` permission. Please see the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html#VOICE_CALL). Although, call recording might intentionally be broken depending on the device target market due to legal restrictions, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178996/mediarecorder-record-calls-application).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately in Android P, if I am not mistaken, google blocked this method. Recently they announced this new API for Android Q, so I was hoping that call recording could be done using it.